# Observer for Abandonment of Cart

Tags: magento2, event-observer

**I need help!!!**

I am creating a module that integrates with another platform via API. I already got the Observer or Event for customer registration (**customer_register_success**), purchase completed (**checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**).

The help I need is how I can get the Observer to abandoned carts?, or what would be the best method to obtain that information and send it via API.

Comment: what is your definition of abadoned carts?

Comment: When the customer added products to the car and did not make the purchase

Comment: Did not make the purchase within 2 minutes, 10 minutes, one hour or a day? Anyway, whatever time you choose for your definition, you can observe an event which happens, and not something which not happens. In my opinion for your usecase the best concept would be a cronjob which checks active quotes with last interaction older than x minutes/hours/days.

Comment: Thank you. Magento when you are making a purchase and close the ecommerce, automatically creates a record that you can see in the admin -> reports -> abandoned Carts.
My question exists is there a way to get that information?

Comment: There is no such event to get it,you can get quote collection which is not ordered between specific time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There is no such event to get abandoned carts,you have to create it
  custom.
- I have idea to overcome this,you have to create cron that run every
  specific time and collect all quote which is not ordered and between
  time you set(difference between created and updated quote time). you
  have to just manage `updatedAtFrom` and `updatedAtTo`
- By doing this you will collect all quotes data and in that collection
  you can dispatch event and pass all quote data and customer data to
  that event within single event or saperate for all quote and pass that data to API from observer.

I have created Script that you can apply in your Block function i'm using this working script for send cart item in mail to my customer after they left without order.

```
<?php 
ob_start();
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$updatedAtFrom = '2019-06-19 19:00:00'; //Add current time
$updatedAtTo   = '2019-06-19 20:30:00';  // $updatedAtFrom  + 90 minutes ,add 90 minutes in current time to abondened cart

        $connection = $resource->getConnection();


        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from(
                ['q' => $resource->getTableName('quote')],
                [
                    'store_id'    => 'q.store_id',
                    'quote_id'    => 'q.entity_id',
                    'customer_id' => 'q.customer_id',
                    'updated_at'  => 'q.updated_at',
                    'created_at'  => 'q.created_at',
                ]
            )
            ->joinLeft(
                ['qa' => $resource->getTableName('quote_address')],
                'q.entity_id = qa.quote_id AND qa.address_type = "billing"',
                [
                    'customer_email'     => new \Zend_Db_Expr('IFNULL(q.customer_email, qa.email)'),
                    'customer_firstname' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('IFNULL(q.customer_firstname, qa.firstname)'),
                    'customer_lastname'  => new \Zend_Db_Expr('IFNULL(q.customer_lastname, qa.lastname)'),
                ]
            )
            ->joinInner(
                ['qi' => $resource->getTableName('quote_item')],
                'q.entity_id = qi.quote_id',
                [
                    'i_created_at' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(qi.created_at)'),
                ]
            )
            ->joinLeft(array('order' => $resource->getTableName('sales_order')),
                'order.quote_id = q.entity_id',
                array()
            )
            ->where('order.entity_id IS NULL')
            ->where('q.is_active = 1')
            ->where('q.items_count > 0')
            ->where('q.customer_email IS NOT NULL OR qa.email IS NOT NULL')
            ->where('qi.parent_item_id IS NULL')
            ->group('q.entity_id')
            ->having(
                '(q.created_at > ? OR MAX(qi.created_at) > ?)',
                $updatedAtFrom
            )
            ->having(
                '(q.created_at < ? OR MAX(qi.created_at) < ?)',
                $updatedAtTo
            )
            ->order('q.updated_at');

        $quotes = $connection->fetchAll($select);


        foreach ($quotes as $quote) {

            $params = [

                'store_id'       => $quote['store_id'],
                'quote_id'              => $quote['quote_id'],
                'customer_id'           => $quote['customer_id'],
                'customer_email' => $quote['customer_email'],
                'customer_tname'  => $quote['customer_firstname'] . ' ' . $quote['customer_lastname'],
                'created_at'     => max($quote['created_at'], $quote['i_created_at']),
            ];

            echo $quote['quote_id'];

            /*$this->eventdispatch->register(
                'quote_abandoned',
                [$params['quote_id']],
                $params
            );*/ 
            // Dispatch Event here and writelogic in that event which you want
        }

?>
```

**Resulted Query of above script is :**

```
SELECT `q`.`store_id`, `q`.`entity_id` AS `quote_id`, `q`.`customer_id`, `q`.`updated_at`, `q`.`created_at`, IFNULL(q.customer_email, qa.email) AS `customer_email`, IFNULL(q.customer_firstname, qa.firstname) AS `customer_firstname`, IFNULL(q.customer_lastname, qa.lastname) AS `customer_lastname`, MAX(qi.created_at) AS `i_created_at` FROM `quote` AS `q` LEFT JOIN `quote_address` AS `qa` ON q.entity_id = qa.quote_id AND qa.address_type = "billing" INNER JOIN `quote_item` AS `qi` ON q.entity_id = qi.quote_id LEFT JOIN `sales_order` AS `order` ON order.quote_id = q.entity_id WHERE (order.entity_id IS NULL) AND (q.is_active = 1) AND (q.items_count > 0) AND (q.customer_email IS NOT NULL OR qa.email IS NOT NULL) AND (qi.parent_item_id IS NULL) GROUP BY `q`.`entity_id` HAVING ((q.created_at > '2019-06-19 19:00:00' OR MAX(qi.created_at) > '2019-06-19 19:00:00')) AND ((q.created_at < '2019-06-19 20:30:00' OR MAX(qi.created_at) < '2019-06-19 20:30:00')) ORDER BY `q`.`updated_at` ASC
```